# Need a script to add a second IP address to a Windows machine

Tags: windows, nic

Does anyone know how to create a .reg registry script that will add a second IP address to a machine that is called 127.0.0.2 ?

Here is the "manual" method:

1. Go to the Control Panel > Network
   Connections  Right click on the
   Local    Area Connection (or
   whichever network    connection you
   want to add the 2nd IP    Address)
   and click  Properties
2. Click    on
   Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) in the
   connection box and click properties 
   Enter the first IP address in the
   properties box
3. Click Advanced
4. Click Add under the IP Addresses box
   and enter the information for the
   2nd    IP Address
5. Close all the
   boxes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not going to want to do this with direct manipulation of the registry. You're much better off using the `netsh` command to make these kinds of changes.

Assuming the NIC is named "Local Area Connection", you can do `netsh interface ip "Local Area Connection" x.x.x.x y.y.y.y` where x.x.x.x is the IP address and y.y.y.y is the subnet mask.

Comment: +1 Wish I could agree more...

Comment: ahh... i should have thought of that!  thanks. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, don't do this when you're remotely and your primary address is DHCP, because it overrides the DHCP.

Comment: Is this really adding a second IP address, or it only replaces the current IP with the new IP (x.x.x.x)?

Answer (score 3):

Late, I know, but I think djangofan want something like that :

```
    netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.110 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.5

    netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection" 172.21.1.10 255.255.0.0 172.21.1.254
```

and the result :

```
Carte Ethernet Connexion au réseau local :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.21.1.10
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.0.110
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.5
                                       172.21.1.254
```

Comment: Thank you.  So long ago that I don't remember why I asked the question.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this when you're remotely and your primary address is DHCP, because it overrides the DHCP.